# How to assign Cell contents to a non-cell array object in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

The Code snippet looks like this:

`legendentry=zeros(1, NumberOfFiles); 
legendentry{1}= sprintf('Experimental');
legendentry{NumberOfFiles} = sprintf('Variable: %.2f', 0.5+(NumberOfFiles-1)*0.5); 
h =legend(legendentry,'Location','southeast');`

And if i run it like this it gives this error message: "Cell contents assignment to a non-cell array object."

If i leave out the first line *`legendentry=zeros(1, NumberOfFiles);`* the Code works fine for me and the Legend looks like i want it to be:

*Experimental*

*Variable: 0.5*

*Variable: 1 ..* and so on..

But then the `legendentry` is not anymore preallocated. So i want to know how i could preallocate the Array correctly if i needed to do that later..

I know that there has to be something with *cellstr* or *num2str*, but i don´t know how to solve it myself.

Hope you guys can help me with this basic issue..

Answer (score 1):

Preallocate `legendentry` [as a cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocate-memory-for-a-cell-array.html) since you're going to assign it cells.

```
legendentry = cell(1, NumberOfFiles);
```

Comment: i also tried this out, but it gives me this error *Cell array argument must be a cell array of strings.* in the  line
 _h= legend(legendentry,'Location','southeast');_.

Comment: What is `NumberOfFiles`? What is the size of `X` and `Y`?

Comment: X & Y are just vectors consisting of doubles (1, 75) and _NumberOfFiles= length(dir([path '\*.txt']))_  Maybe i have to format them?

Comment: Provide the output you get after executing that line (`NumberOfFiles= length(dir([path '*.txt']))`)

Comment: just a double-value which represents all the .txt-files in the folder

Comment: depends on the amount of .txt-files. so currently it´s 5.

Comment: The code you've provided that you've claimed that it gives the correct output with `NumberOfFiles` equals `5` and `X` and `Y` as 1x75  vectors after removing the line `legendentry=zeros(1, NumberOfFiles)`; that's really not possible. See [MCVE]

Comment: But in what extent does the actual legend-function depend on the plot function?. In my code the legend-function just depends on the amount of files in the folder where i stored them. So actually the plot-function has no impact on the legend-function right?

Comment: Please create a [MCVE] before proceeding to next questions without which it is unclear what you're asking. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks as well.. and i deleted the *plot*-part because it has nothing to do with it in my opinion

Comment: Removing those two lines doesn't make your question a [MCVE]. Please read that link and edit your question accordingly. The plot part has everything to do with the legend.

Comment: The error `Cell array argument must be a cell array of strings` in the line `h= legend(legendentry,'Location','southeast');` is due to the fact that some elements of `legendentry` are not strings. You may want to initialize `legendentry = repmat({''}, 1, NumberOfFiles);`. Also you are just setting the first and last value of `legendentry`, which may not be what you are trying to do?